# Is there a way to fake a synchronous XHR request?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, synchronous, web-worker

I'm porting a pile of C++ code to Javascript using the Emscripten system. The C++ code has many calls to `fopen` which is a synchronous IO call. Within Emscripten, we simulate this using an XHR request to a local resource *however*, within Firefox synchronous XHR calls (with a `responseType` of `blob` or `arraybuffer`) are only supported within a Web-Worker. Converting all that c++ code to adapt to asynchronous IO code seems very complicated so for my first try, I'd like to see if I can fake a synchronous XHR request.

My initial thought was that the main loop could share some state with a web-worker which could make the synchronous io call and update the shared state while the main loop paused and waited for the web-worker finished. DISCLAIMER: I know this is not the typical Javascript way but I am porting synchronous code, not writing new code from scratch (in which I would definitely have used asynchronous IO).

Given the restrictions on sharing state between a web-worker and the main-loop, this idea looks untenable.

Are there other ways to do this?

Comment: *"within Firefox synchronous XHR calls are only supported within a Web-Worker"* That sure doesn't sound right.

Comment: This is where I'm getting this info:

https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Filesystem-Guide

"WARNING: Firefox and Chrome have recently disabled synchronous binary XHRs, which means this cannot work"

Comment: @squint The OP didn't explain it well (until his comment above), but it's further explained on MDN's [XHR page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest): "Starting with Gecko 11.0... as well as WebKit build 528, these browsers no longer let you use the `responseType` attribute when performing synchronous requests." This means you cannot get binary data back using a `responseType` of "`arraybuffer`" or "`blob`"; this is being done (I assume) to explicitly discourage fetching (potentially quite large) binary resources in a synchronous way.

Comment: It's a real bummer because that's exactly what C++ ported code is likely to do.

Comment: There is definitely no way to wrap asynchronous behavior inside a synchronous function. There is also no way to get a synchronous result from a Web worker, as they only communicate via asynchronous events. The only possible solution I can think of is to not set `responseType` (thereby allowing synchronous fetches), handle the response as raw text, and somehow convert it back into clean binary data in an arraybuffer.

Comment: I am not sure whether I _really_ get your problem right. But don't you just try to do several requests on one or more resources, one after the other, with the second waiting for the first's response (and so on)?

Comment: you could find a way to detect every URL that will be fetched by ajax before the app boots; maybe a regexp or a more formalized build step. It need not be perfect, and extra garbage is ok. You then load all the data from disk using async ajax to build a look-up-table object, keys being the url and value the response. You can then make virtual sync requests to the object by re-defining your sync ajax function. Once the files are pre-loaded, fire up your app as normal.

Comment: @MichaelBishop, instead of trying to make the code synchronous, try setting up a callback queue or a set of promises so that writing your code involves fewer nested callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

So after seeing all the answers and doing some of my own reading, it appears the best answer is: "You can, but only for text data and you have to convert it back to binary data". This is slow, but does work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FSending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#Receiving_binary_data_in_older_browsers

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at testing libraries like qunit and sinon? I think Jasmine may also be able to do it, but I know that sinon can do this

http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server