# Syncrhonous Cross-Domain AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain

Suppose the following directory structure:

```
/web
    example.html
    example.js
/example.json
```

I open example.html with my browser and it runs example.js, which tries to load the data in example.json synchronously using the following call:

```
$.ajax({url: "file:///example.json",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            console.log(request);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
        }
});
```

This results in an error with message "Access to restricted URI denied" and error code 1012. So far, I have taken a look at [Access to restricted URI denied“ code: ”1012 - Cross domain Ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681470/access-to-restricted-uri-denied-code-1012-cross-domain-ajax-request) and [Access to restricted URI denied code: 1012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283/access-to-restricted-uri-denied-code-1012). The first link suggested that I use jQuery's [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method, but this method only works asynchronously. The second link suggests some sort of JSONP callback, but I haven't been able to understand how exactly these work.

Note that this problem easily goes away if I move example.json to /web/example.json, but I would like to avoid this due to some circumstances of my actual problem (what I presented here is a simplification of my actual problem).

EDIT: I am trying this JSONP code, but I am still running into the same error:

```
$.ajax({url: "file:///example.json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
        console.log(request);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why does it need to be synchronous? Why not just delay execution of specific code until callback function is triggered?

Comment: The reason for using AJAX is because it is asynchronous. The reason is lost when you make it synchronous :(

Comment: @Vega The reason I am using AJAX is because it can load my JSON data, not because it is asynchronous. If there is an alternative that can also load my JSON data, I would be happy to hear about it.

Comment: @Vega There are scenarios where synchronous ajax is the only solution.

Comment: @abw333 The alternative is your web server requesting the JSON data and serving it to the client.

Comment: @BradM Making this request synchronous would make my code simpler. I'm actually executing this request inside a for loop and I don't want to do anything until all the requests have fetched their JSON data. Also. I'm not using a web server. This is all local and I would like to keep it that way for simplicity's sake.

Comment: in what scenarios is synchronous the only solution? if synchronous is the only solution, you're working in an environment that needs to be updated/replaced. Back on topic, the cross-domain request you're making will not work in chrome regardless of what you do because it's `file://` unless you started chrome with lesser security settings. I suggest working from two domains rather than a domain and the file system if you want to test a cross-domain request.

Comment: Sending ajax requests in a loop while keeping them asynchronous is very easy and maintainable using the promise interface.

Comment: @KevinB Lets say a user closes their browser and you want to send an ajax request during the unload event; synchronous is your only option.

Comment: @KevinB When [compiling synchronous C++ operations to JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281511/is-there-a-way-to-fake-a-synchronous-xhr-request) (e.g., by using [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/)), sometimes you can only use a synchronous operation. That said, I won't necesarily disagree with your assertion that if you're compiling your C++ into JS that your "environment that needs to be updated/replaced".

Answer (score 0):

By default cross-domain AJAX requests are not allowed. You need permission from the other server using [CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185576/crossdomain-ajax-request-using-corshttp://), or you can use JSONP.

Comment: JSONP can't be synchronous though.

Comment: @Diodeus Take a look at the edit I just made to the question. Do you know why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning for using synchronous ajax is misguided. If you want to wait until all ajax requests complete, use the following methodology.

```
var ajaxRequest1 = $.ajax();
var ajaxRequest2 = $.ajax();
var ajaxRequest3 = $.ajax();
$.when(ajaxRequest1, ajaxRequest2, ajaxRequest3).done(function(){});
```

This will be far more efficient/faster than executing a series of synchronous ajax requests inside a loop.

Comment: What if I don't know how many AJAX requests will be executed until runtime? (It depends on user input)

Comment: Then you pass an array/collection of jqXHR objects. `$.when.apply($, ajaxRequestArray)`

Comment: I'll let you know in a few moments :)

Comment: So the change to asynchronous requests worked, but I'm still having the original "Access to restricted URI denied" error. Now I should use JSONP?

Comment: @abw333 Yes, you should use JSONP.

Comment: I'm having difficulties with JSONP. Could you take look at the edit I made to the original question?

Comment: Those web services need to be configured to handle JSONP requests.

Comment: They are not a web service. This is all local.

Comment: Ok, so configure it to handle JSONP.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34173/discussion-between-abw333-and-brad-m)

Answer (score 0):

Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.

[Look at documentation here.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)